# How to suspend Camel routes only in an interval of time

Tags: apache-camel, suspend

The application I'm working on is a Apache Camel middleware which handles interactions among several applications. I'll try to summarize the problem we're encountering.

**Route 1:**

- Whenever there is a change in the "Application 1", our application is notified through differents SOAP events, then our application will do some treatments.
- This "Route 1" starts with a SOAP endpoint, NOT a scheduler.

Now the client wants us to set up a hotfix for another business requirements change. So we will implement a new route :

**Route 2:**

- When the client puts a txt file in the input folder, the treatment will begin.
- The delicat problem is that once this treatment finishes, there will be some changes in the "Application 1", and our application risks to get some unwanted notifications through the "Route 1". Note that those kinds of notifications are always needed for business requirements, BUT they are not just after this hotfix treatment.
- So we think about running the hotfix out of work hours : the client will put the txt file himself in the input folder between 7pm and midnight.

The question is : How can we automatically deactivate the "**Route 1**" for hotfix time (between 7pm and midnight), then automatically resume this "**Route 1**" after the hotfix ?

Thank you for your help.

Application 1 notifies us through Route 1 :

```
from("soapEndpoint")
    .routeId("route1")
    .process(treatment 1)
    .end();
```

Hotfix, the treatment 2 may be followed by some changes in Application 1 which emit events that are listened by Route 1 :

```
from("fileEndpoint")
    .routeId("route2")
    .process(treatment 2)
    .end();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a scheduled route policy to stop and start your route at certain times. See [SimpleScheduledRoutePolicy](https://camel.apache.org/simplescheduledroutepolicy.html)